# How to install windows 7 after fedora 16

Tags: fedora, system-installation, windows

I have Fedora 16, but I want to play games, and I´m considering installing Windows 7.

I need to be able to dual boot these two OS. Is there something special I´m supposed to do, or it will work like a charm (I put the DVD, install Windows 7 with x/3 disk space and voila, it works)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate a partition for Windows (either primary partition or logical).

Install windows to that partition, and when it's done, boot with your LiveCD and fix grub.

**How to recover Linux boot after that?**

Boot with another system, e.g your Fedora LiveCD, chroot into your root partition, and run `grub-setup /dev/XXX` to install the boot loader and re-build your grub menu file (to add loader for Windows 7).

Mount:

```
mount /dev/XX /mnt/XX
```

Chroot:

```
mount --bind /dev /mnt/XX/dev
chroot /mnt/XX
```

Now fix grub:

```
grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-setup /dev/XX
```

I've done this multiple times, it is both possible and easy.

Comment: 10x for the quick answer. What means ´fix grub´?

Comment: @fiction , please see my update